# Passing an array as parameters not working. What could be the error?

Tags: java

I passed the var array as an argument to the quadraticalc method and used it to perform operations but i want to return two values..but giving me errors

```
package testingequality;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Sum {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //comparison ();

        double [] var = new double [3];
        int counter;
        Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
        for (counter = 0; counter< var.length; counter++)
        {
            System.out.println ("Input value for a,b,c");
            var [counter] = input.nextDouble();
        }

        double [] sum = quadraticalc (var);
        for (int i = 0; i < sum.length; i++)
        {
        System.out.println (sum [i]);
}
    }
     public static double [] quadraticalc (double [] var)
    {
         double a,b,c,d,e;
         double [] x = new double [2];
         a = var [0];
         b = var [1];
         c = var [2] ;
         d = (b*b)-(4*a*c);
         e =  Math.sqrt(d);
         double x1 = (-b + e)/ (2 * a);
         double x2 = (-b - e)/ (2 * a);
         x [0] = x1;
         x [1] = x2;
         return x; 

    }
}
```

I made a little change to the code and i was able to get the right answer now.. thanks to all that contributed

Comment: "but giving me errors" What error is it showing?

Comment: What's the error? Could you show us the stack trace?

Comment: No details of the errors?

Comment: When I run your program, I get no errors.  The closest thing I can get to an error is to give values such that d is negative, so that x1 and x2 are NaN.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of printing the array reference, you should print the values inside the array.

Change:

```
System.out.println (sum);
```

to:

```
System.out.println (sum[0]);
System.out.println (sum[1]);
```

Comment: I tryed using the suggestion but for variables a,b,c , the output is returning 0.0 and 0.0

Answer (score 0):

Going out on a limb here ...
You need to pretty print the contents of the array.  Try

```
Arrays.toString(sum)
```

But, of course, you could have other issues ...

Answer (score 0):

So I ran your code. There are no errors, but I think you're getting something printed like `[D@330bedb4` and you believe it is an error. Rather this is perfectly acceptable behavior. At

```
System.out.println (sum);
```

I think that you expect the numbers to be printed. In reality though, Java prints the array object, which doesn't have a pretty string representation. So instead, you want to print the doubles that are found *within* the array. Something like this will do

```
for (int i=0; i < sum.length; i++) {
    System.out.println(sum[i]);
}
```

I got NaN when I did this, so there must be something wrong with quadraticalc and how you are calculating values.

EDIT: This is because if d is negative, e (the sqrt of d) will not be a real number. If you are calculating the quadratic, you maybe want a check for that.

I changed your quadratic function for easier readability to

```
public static double [] quadraticalc (double [] var)
{
    double a = var [0];
    double b = var [1];
    double c = var [2];

    System.out.println("a = " + a + ", b = " + b + ", c = " + c);

    double root1 = (-b + Math.sqrt(Math.pow(b, 2) - 4*a*c)) / (2*a);
    double root2 = (-b - Math.sqrt(Math.pow(b, 2) - 4*a*c)) / (2*a);

    return new double[] { root1, root2 };
}
```

Example run (I printed the a, b, c, d, and e values for visibility)

```
Input value for a,b,c
10 100 10
Input value for a,b,c
Input value for a,b,c
a = 10.0, b = 100.0, c = 10.0, d = 9600.0, e = 97.97958971132712
-0.10102051443364388
-9.898979485566356
```

These answers are correct and can be verified @ http://www.math.com/students/calculators/source/quadratic.htm

Comment: I tryed using the suggestion but for variables a,b,c , the output is returning 0.0 and 0.0

Comment: What are your inputs?

Comment: 1,5,6.. also tryed 1,4,4

Comment: My bad, I altered something earlier..I just checked tru, u were right.. thanks for the help

Comment: Why did you revoke my answer?